# Loading custom dll + custom app fails with: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, qt, dll, shared-libraries

My environment is:

- Debian Linux 8 x86
- Qt 5.3.1 installed in /opt (to avoid conflict with
  system installed Qt)
- QtCreator 3.4.2
- gcc 4.9.2

While creating my app I've decided to split some functionality into several parts. So I've created subfolder project (`main`) with 2 folders/subprojects (`UI` and `logics`), like that:

- main

  - UI
  - logics

when `UI` is default Qt Widget Application (main.cpp and window). `logics` is very simple shared library with empty class `Logics` (empty constructor and nothing else more). I've added

```
DESTDIR = $$PWD/../UI
```

to `logics.pro` so final `logics.so` will be created inside `UI` folder.
to `UI.pro` i've added

```
LIBS += -L $$PWD -llogics
```

to link `UI` executable with `logics.so`

Now when I run executable from `UI` project with `QtCreator` I get strange error:

> UI: error while loading shared libraries: liblogics.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

The error only exists when `Logics` class derived from `QObject`. It looks like `logics.so` cannot find `Qt` library. but when I query its dependencies I see no problem:

> *ldd logics.so*
>
> ```
>     linux-gate.so.1 (0xb770d000)
>     libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
>     ...
> ```

If the `Logics` class is independed from `Qt` I mean, when I remove `QObject`, the error gone.

But I cannot add this Qt library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just because it will conflict with system installed Qt libraries.

So my question - how can I run my main `UI` project from QtCreator with my custom linked shared library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after searching the Internet I've found (and I was very surprised) that a Linux executable doesn't include current folder in libraries search path by default. Although executable and library are in some folder the executable will fail to load *.so library.

So there are at least 2 solutions:

1. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include current folder (or some specified folder)

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

2. set [Rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath). In `*.pro` file add the following line:

> QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,.